# Algorithm to extract elements from weighted queues

Tags: java, algorithm, queue, priority-queue, weighted

I'm trying to implement a kind of 'weighted queue extractor' to extract elements from different queues having different priorities. I just have to choose the queue I've to get an element from.

Let's say I have n queues, each with a priority. Priority indicates how many elements need to be extracted from the queue relative to the others. For instance, if I have n=2 queues where one (A) has a priority of 5 and the other (B) has a priority of 10, after 15 extractions from the queues, I should have taken out 5 elements from queue A and 10 from queue B. The extractions should occur uniformly.

As an example, I should extract 2 elements from queue B, then one element from queue A, and so forth. If I have 3 queues — A, B, C — with priorities 1, 3, 6, then every 10 extractions should yield 1 element from queue A, 3 from queue B, and 6 from queue C. For example, in this sequence: C B C A C B C C B C (so I got 1 from A, 3 from B, 6 from C).

My idea is to envision each queue as a runner. In this scenario, runner A is slow, moving at 1 step/sec, runner B at 3 s/s, and runner C at 6 s/s. The runner reaching the finish line first goes back a fixed distance, A+B+C steps (in this case, 1+3+6=10). The others continue at their own pace, covering the distance according to their speed. Every time I send someone back, I extract an element from that queue. Consider this example:

```
 A  B  C
 1  3  6 --> Who is the largest posotive? 6 (i.e., C). I move it back by 10 steps.
 1  3 -4 --> Who is the largest positive? 3 (i.e., B). I move it back by 10 steps. C is negative, so I advance it at its pace (6).
 1 -7  2 --> Who is the largest positive? 2 (i.e., C), and I move it back by 10 steps. B is negative, so I advance it at its pace (3).
 1 -4 -8 --> Who is the largest positive? 1 (i.e., A), and I move it back by 10 steps; B and C are negative, so I advance them at their respective paces.
-9 -1 -2 --> No positive values... I advance them without extracting anyone.
-8  2  4 --> I take the largest positive, the 4 (i.e., C), and move them back by 10 steps, etcetera.
-7  2 -6  --> I get the 2 (aka B) and move it back 10 steps, then I advance the others at their respective paces
-6 -8  0  --> skip
-5 -5  6  --> I get the 6 (aka C) and move it back 10 steps, and let the others run at their pace
-4 -2 -4  --> skip
-3  1  2  --> I get the 2 (aka C) and move him back
-2  1 -8  --> I get 1 (aka B) and move him back
-1 -9 -2  --> skip
 0 -6  4  --> I get 4 (aka C) and move him back
```

So, after 10,000 iterations, I expect to have extracted 1000 elements from group A, 3000 from group B, and 6000 from group C. However, I obtained 1346, 2885, 5769. I suspect an error in the algorithm, but I'm unsure where or what it might be.

This is the class I wrote:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class FairQueue
    {

        private int[] values;
        private int[] priorities;
        private int total = 0;

        public FairQueue(int[] priorities, int[] values)
        {
            this.values = values;
            this.priorities = priorities;
            for (int priority : priorities) {
                total += priority;
            }
            if (this.values == null) {
                this.values = Arrays.copyOf(priorities, priorities.length);
            }
        }

        public int getIndex()
        {
            int toret = -1;
            while (toret == -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    if (values[i] <= 0) {
                        values[i] += priorities[i];
                    } else { // got positive value
                        if (toret == -1) {
                            toret = i;
                        } else { // if I find a better positive
                            if (values[toret] < values[i]) {
                                // should it run? 
                                // values[toret] += priorities[toret];
                                toret = i;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            // go back!
            values[toret] -= total;
            return toret;
        }

        int getTotal()
        {
            return total;
        }

        private static final int ITERATIONS = 1000;
        // with { 1,2,3,4 } it works fine!
        // private static final int[] PRIORITIES = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        private static final int[] PRIORITIES = new int[] { 1, 3, 6 };

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            FairQueue f = new FairQueue(PRIORITIES, null);
            int[] res = new int[PRIORITIES.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS * f.getTotal(); i++) {
                res[f.getIndex()]++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < PRIORITIES.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("p[%d]=%d: %d elemn (%.2f)", i, PRIORITIES[i], res[i],
                        (1.0 * res[i]) / PRIORITIES[i]));
            }


        }

    }
```

Probably, known the first 10 extractions, I can just repeat them... but I prefer to fix the algorithm.

Any hints would be appreciated. :)

***PS** - I also suppose that I could create a function f(k) that, given an extraction number, reports the exact queue element (so, it's O(1) and it doesn't need an algorithm). In the previosu example, f(0)=2 (aka C), f(5)=1 (aka B), f(3)=0 (aka A).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the algorithm issue.
Whenever I find a positive number, I have to extract that element and decrease its value of the related priority. If I don't have positive elements, I have to add the queue priority to the value. Example:

```
 A  B  C
---------
 1  3  6   ->  A 
-9  3  6   ->  B
-9 -7  6   ->  C
-9 -7 -4
-8 -4  2   ->  C
-8 -4 -8
-7 -1 -2
-6  2  4   ->  B
-6 -8  4   ->  C
-6 -8 -6
-5 -5  0   ->  C
-5 -5 -10 
-4 -2 -4
-4  1  2   ->  B
-4 -9  2   ->  C
-4 -9 -8
-3 -6 -2
-2 -3  4   ->  C
-2 -3 -6
-1  0  0   ->  B
-1 -10 0   ->  C
-1 -10 -10 
 0 -7 -3   ->  A
etc etc
```

Fixed the algorithm, the result is correct:

```
    public int getIndex() {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                // any positive value?
                if (values[i] >= 0) {
                    values[i] -= total;
                    return i;
                }
            }
            // no positive values here
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                values[i] += priorities[i];
            }
        }
    }
```